# How to check if a vector hirogramm correlates with uniform distribution?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a vector of floats `V` with values from 0 to 1. I want to create a histogram with some window say `A==0.01`. And check how close is the resulting histogram to uniform distribution getting one value from zero to one where `0` is correlating perfectly and `1` meaning not correlating at all. For me correlation here first of all means histogram shape.
How one would do such a thing in python with numpy?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the histogram with `np.histogram`. Then, you can generate the uniform histogram from the average of the previously retrieved histogram with `np.mean`. Then you can use a statistical test like the Pearson coefficient to do that with `scipy.stats.pearsonr`.